# Outlook Reminders to E-Mail Script -- But Can't Dismiss

Tags: vba, email, outlook, dismiss, reminders

I have looked into previous answers and tried many variations on the below, but I cannot seem to get it to work.

Basically, the purpose of the script below is to turn Outlook reminders into e-mail messages.

However, I cannot seem to programmatically dismiss the reminders.  I've looked into prior answers to these questions (such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13283989/dismiss-outlook-reminder)) and attempted to implement them, but they don't seem to succeed in this configuration.

```
' declare this object withEvents displaying all the events
Private WithEvents olRemind As Outlook.Reminders
Private Sub Application_Reminder(ByVal Item As Object)
  Dim objMsg As MailItem
  Dim objRem As Reminder
  Dim olRemind As Reminders
  Set olRemind = Outlook.Reminders
  Set objMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
  objMsg.To = "*ADDRESS REMOVED FROM EXAMPLE*"
  objMsg.subject = "MHReminder: " + Item.subject
  objMsg.Body = Item.Body
  Set objMsg.SaveSentMessageFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDeletedItems)
  objMsg.Send
  Set objMsg = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub olRemind_BeforeReminderShow(Cancel As Boolean)

    For Each objRem In olRemind
        If objRem.IsVisible = True Then
            objRem.Dismiss
            Cancel = True
        End If
    Exit For
    Next objRem

End Sub
```

I'm a bit more of a "kludge-and-splice" programmer than a true programmer, so would appreciate anyone pointing out my (hopefully obvious) errors.

Thank you ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking at the first found reminder then quitting with

```
Exit For
```

As in the example you found [Dismiss Outlook reminder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13283989/dismiss-outlook-reminder) you will need something like

```
For Each objRem In objRems
    If objRem.Caption = "TESTING" Then ' <--
        If objRem.IsVisible Then
            objRem.Dismiss
        End If
        Exit For
    End If
Next objRem
```

Comment: If this is the answer, do not accept. Delete the question.

Comment: That doesn't seem to apply here -- basically, the script is supposed to convert ANY triggered reminder to e-mail, so I'm not seeking to test based on a caption.

Comment: The answer is really the same. You are processing the first reminder found then Exiting. To process every reminder drop the Exit For. I think though you will have to figure out how to identify the reminder that triggers each email and cancel only that one.

Comment: How is for each reminder in Outlook.Reminders processing only the first one?

Answer (score 0):

Cancel parameter in the BeforeReminderShow event handler needs to be `ByRef`.